# graph plotting with not euclidean distance matrix

Tags: d3.js, plot, gnuplot

I got a distance matrix: V x V x distance where the distance is not euclidean (triangle equation does **not** hold). 
I do not have any possibility to get coordinates from the distance matrix.

How can I plot a graph based on the matrix in 2d or 3d in d3.js or gnuplot?
i.e. in some force directed graph or something.

I thought about some force-directed graph where the forces between two nodes are defined by their distance such that the non eucledian property is not important.

Comment: If you have something that gives you coordinates from the distance matrix, you can plot it with whatever you like. At least D3 won't plot directly even from a Euclidean distance matrix -- you need the node positions.

Comment: I do not have any possibility to get coordinates from the distance matrix. How can I plot a graph based on the matrix in 2d or 3d in d3.js or gnuplot? i.e. in some force directed graph or something.

Comment: You can't do this in D3 without Euclidean or similar distances.

Comment: I thought about some force-directed graph where the forces between two nodes are defined by their distance or similarity such that the non euclidean property is not important. But i dont know how to do this in d3js.

Comment: Well you could use [`.linkDistance()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkDistance) for that, but I'm not sure if that would work well with your distances. They're also not hard constraints, i.e. you're not guaranteed to get that distance.

Comment: yes the weakness of the constraints was my bet. I want a visual approximation of what the distances are based upon those non euclidean distances. I hoped someone knew a better way.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21595398/3128209) describes how to set linkDistance based on data, but as @LarsKotthoff says, the results you get will be approximations.  Both the non-Euclidean nature of the graph and crowding of nodes will cause variations in the actual length.